# boost::function & boost::lambda again

Tags: c++, boost

Follow-up to post: [Using * Width & Precision Specifiers With boost::format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978096/using-width-precision-specifiers-with-boostformat)

I'm trying to use `boost::function` to create a function that uses lambdas to format a string with `boost::format`.  Ultimately what I'm trying to achieve is using width & precision specifiers for strings with format. `boost::format` does not support the use of the `*` width & precision specifiers, as indicated [in the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/format/doc/format.html#printf_directives):

> Width or precision set to asterisk (*)
>   are used by printf to read this field
>   from an argument. e.g.
>   printf("%1$d:%2$.*3$d:%4$.*3$d\n",
>   hour, min, precision, sec); This class
>   does not support this mechanism for
>   now. so such precision or width fields
>   are quietly ignored by the parsing.

so I'm trying to find other ways to accomplish the same goal.

Here is what I have so far, which isn't working:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost\function.hpp>
#include <boost\lambda\lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost\format.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost\bind.hpp>

int main()
{
 using namespace boost::lambda;
 using namespace std;

 boost::function<std::string(int, std::string)> f =
  (boost::format("%s") % boost::io::group(setw(_1*2), setprecision(_2*2), _3)).str();

 std::string s = (boost::format("%s") % f(15, "Hello")).str();

    return 0;
}
```

This generates many compiler errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: hacks, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Compiling...
1>main.cpp
1>.\main.cpp(15) : error C2872: '_1' : ambiguous symbol
1>        could be 'D:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_42\boost/lambda/core.hpp(69) : boost::lambda::placeholder1_type &boost::lambda::`anonymous-namespace'::_1'
1>        or       'D:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_42\boost/bind/placeholders.hpp(43) : boost::arg<I> `anonymous-namespace'::_1'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            I=1
1>        ]
1>.\main.cpp(15) : error C2664: 'std::setw' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::lambda::placeholder1_type' to 'std::streamsize'
1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>.\main.cpp(15) : error C2872: '_2' : ambiguous symbol
1>        could be 'D:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_42\boost/lambda/core.hpp(70) : boost::lambda::placeholder2_type &boost::lambda::`anonymous-namespace'::_2'
1>        or       'D:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_42\boost/bind/placeholders.hpp(44) : boost::arg<I> `anonymous-namespace'::_2'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            I=2
1>        ]
1>.\main.cpp(15) : error C2664: 'std::setprecision' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'boost::lambda::placeholder2_type' to 'std::streamsize'
1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>.\main.cpp(15) : error C2872: '_3' : ambiguous symbol
1>        could be 'D:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_42\boost/lambda/core.hpp(71) : boost::lambda::placeholder3_type &boost::lambda::`anonymous-namespace'::_3'
1>        or       'D:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_42\boost/bind/placeholders.hpp(45) : boost::arg<I> `anonymous-namespace'::_3'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            I=3
1>        ]
1>.\main.cpp(15) : error C2660: 'boost::io::group' : function does not take 3 arguments
1>.\main.cpp(15) : error C2228: left of '.str' must have class/struct/union
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\john\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\hacks\x64\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>hacks - 7 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

My fundamental understanding of boost's lambdas and functions is probably lacking.  How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that, for this case, you would want to use boost.bind instead of boost.lambda. Part of the problem is that boost::io::group is a function template that takes and returns a variable number of objects, making it difficult to create the appropriate signature for the function<> declaration. I would create a string formatting function with a simple signature and then use boost.bind to create a specific formatting functor from that. i.e.

```
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

string fmt_str(const string& s, int w, int p)
{
    return (format("%s") % io::group(setw(w), setprecision(p), s)).str();
}

int main()
{
    function<string (int, string)> f = bind(fmt_str, _2, _1, _1);
    string s = f(15, "Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check the documentation of Boost.Lambda again and see what it is capable of and what not. For example, since the dot operator is not overloadable you can't invoke a member function like `str()` on a lambda expression like that. You need to use `bind` for this:

```
bind(&format::str, … )
```

This actually extends to all non-operator function calls as far as I can tell. As for creating a format object you need to defer the creation of it via something like this:

```
constructor<boost::format>(constant("%s"))  // untested
```

You see that with all the extra noise (bind, constructor, constant) you get a rather complex, long, and hard to decipher lambda expression. The best thing is probably to avoid it altogether and just use a simple function object

```
struct myfunctor {
    string operator()(int a, string b) const {
        return …
    }
};
…
void foo() {
    …
    boost::function<string(int, string)> f = myfunctor();
    …
}
```