# boost format to set up fixed width with a variable

Tags: c++, boost

I want to use a variable to control the word width. Is it possible in `boost::format`? The `len` is determined at runtime.

Example:

```
string a="a",b="bb",c="321";
int len = 4;

cout << boost::format("%1%  %|%2%t|%3% \n") % a % len % c;
cout << boost::format("%1%  %|%2%t|%3% \n") % b % len % c;
//cout << boost::format("%1%  %|4t|%2% \n") % b % c;  // I know this works.
```

Print out:

```
a   321
bb  321
```

Comment: Found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978096/using-width-precision-specifiers-with-boostformat

Comment: yeah I was going to link same answer